# Modules calling modules is not working. Why?

Tags: django, python-3.x

I have an app in my project and I created some extra modules within it.
When I can these modules within the views.py it works very well. However when I try to call them in other modules, it says that the module that I'm trying to import does not exist.

This is the message:

**AttributeError at /user-dashboard-dividas
module 'pri' has no attribute 'conversationModulesTests'**

The name of the app is 'pri'

I have the 'conversationModulesTests' and 'conversationModulesActions'.

I import both of them in 'views.py' and it works fine.
But when I try to call 'conversationModulesActions' within 'conversationModulesTests' it gives me that response.

My code in 'conversationModulesTests':

```
import pri.conversationModulesActions as CMA
```

What I am missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming your modules are in the same package, perhaps try `from . import conversationModulesActions as CMA`

Comment: Hey, Kintori. I continued trying to solve this issue and came up with this exactly solution! Either way. Thanks!